# How do I compare commits in XCode 13?

Tags: xcode

So I am trying to compare commits in a project I just cloned.

I have put the editor in the comparison mode:

[image]

And I try to select a commit from the menu which appears when I select a comparison point from the bottom selector here:

[image]

But when I do this, I only see the last two commits (the one I cloned, and the one commit I made since then) in the list.

When I run a `git log` command in the terminal, I can see many commits.

How can I access this complete history in XCode?

Comment: I think Xcode only shows commits that changed the file you're looking at. The `git log` command shows full history of all commits. I'm not sure if Xcode provides a way to see and compare any commits, but you can do that from the terminal using `git diff sha_first sha_second`. Just provide the SHAs of the two commits as arguments and you'll see the full diff of all files that were changed between the two commits.

Comment: Ok makes sense!